# How can we get a distribution only by applying a log?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i'm trying to understand how to implement actor critic network. But i don't understand the action probability distribution with log. How can we get a distribution only by applying a log?

Here is the part i don't really understand:

```
# Sample action from action probability distribution
action = np.random.choice(num_actions, p=np.squeeze(action_probs))
action_probs_history.append(tf.math.log(action_probs[0, action]))
```

This is the complete code
https://keras.io/examples/rl/actor_critic_cartpole/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't, where did you read that this is the case?

Comment: Hi Dr. Snoopy. I don't know. So why calculate a log in this case? 

Thanks for your answer !